# How does Ubuntu pass env vars to PHP/apache2 without the "E" variables_order?

Tags: apache2, php

I was pleasantly surprised by how easy it is to set an env var in Ubuntu for use in PHP. But I am curious how it is done. I noticed `/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini` had `variables_order = "GPCS"`. On other systems, I have to change that to `EGPCS` in order to expose an env var to PHP.

Comment: it is PHP that does that  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order

Comment: But, there appears to be a difference in how PHP is configured in Ubuntu/Debian vs other distros. I checked php.ini in Ubuntu and it is set to `variables_order = "GPCS"`. So where else is PHP being allowed to expose environment variables?